# How can I get image url in queryset.values()?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I have a user model like this:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    ...
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True) 
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to=content_file_name)


def content_file_name(obj, filename):

    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = "profile_pic_{0}.{1}".format(str(obj.user.id), str(ext))
    return os.path.join(filename)
```

I know I can get the profile_pic image media path using `user.profile_pic.url`.

**But, how can I get the image media path in** `queryset.values()`**?**

I tried this `queryset.values("profile_pic_url")` and `queryset.values("profile_pic__url")` but It doesn't work.

I can annotate the profile_pic using F-Objects and add the media path as a prefix using f-string like below

```
users = queryset.annotate(image_path=F("profile_pic")).values("image_path")
and then I can add prefix like f"/media/{user.image_path}"
```

Comment: You can't access model/field methods or attributes in a `values()` query, why do you need to have the url in your values?

Comment: @lain Shelvington I can't use serializer class for a specific task. So, I have to use .values() for retrieving few other model related data for further validation. So why I'm wondering If there's a way of doing.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure about getting image url in queryset.values() but I have another solution for you.

You can use `{% get_media_prefix %}` on Django template to get `MEDIA_URL` and then use `{{user.profile_pic}}`

Ex:

```
<img src="{% get_media_prefix %}{{user.profile_pic}}/>
```

It will be rendered as

```
<img src="media/<path_to_profile_pic>" />
```

Ref about {% get_media_prefix %} : [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#get-media-prefix)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that in values() there is any way coz i was also stuck in this the only solution I came across was this.

```
product_image_url = []
for image in bundle_product_images:
    print("@@@@@@@@",image.image.url)
    product_image_url.append(image.image.url)
```

But if you want to use this on templates then the best way is to use Jinja.

```
{% for image in images %}
{{image.url}}
{% endfor%}
```